# VC++ compiler crashes when compiling a simplest piece of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-construction

My compiler is VC++ 2013 and 2013 Novmember CTP.

The following code makes the VC++ compiler crash and report:

**"fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler."**

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    operator T*() const
    {
        return p;
    }

    T* p;
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    using A::operator T*;
};

int main()
{}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably a bug in the VC++ compiler, but your code is still incorrect: g++ reports `error: 'template<class T> class A' used without template parameters` ([link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5bc0077ddea4539)). (That's often a good idea to test code on different compilers.)

Change line 15 from

```
    using A::operator T*;
```

to

```
    using A<T>::operator T*;
```

(i.e. change “`A`” to “`A<T>`”).

Comment: It's OK to write as `using A<T>::operator T*;`